# Why JUMP opcode costs more than the rest

Tags: gas, opcode

Looking [here](https://github.com/djrtwo/evm-opcode-gas-costs/blob/master/opcode-gas-costs_EIP-150_revision-1e18248_2017-04-12.csv#L51), most of the basic opcodes are 3 while `JUMP` is 8. Wondering why this is, why the 3x multiplier on this instruction.

Comment: On "traditional" architectures, a branch (if/else) operation is usually compiled into a JUMP followed by a few NOPs. Since miners ultimately run their mining application on some "traditional" architecture, perhaps this is why JUMP is ascribed with a higher cost than that of other opcodes.